# How to simply Scale an object in openGL?

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to learn how to do scaling, rotating, and translating in openGL, but I am not sure exactly how to do so. I tried following an example but it is not working. Below is my sample code, which does not draw the object. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLfloat vertices[][2] = { { -1.0,1.0 },{ -1.0,0.857 },
{ -0.857,0.857 },{ -0.857,1.0 } };

void drawObject() {

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2fv(vertices[0]);
    glVertex2fv(vertices[1]);
    glVertex2fv(vertices[2]);
    glVertex2fv(vertices[3]);
    glEnd();
}

void display(void)
{

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(2.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    drawObject();
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1600, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Don't use single buffering; double buffering is much preferred in this era. What is the result? After scaling, your primitive would cover the entire screen, and would be totally black.

Comment: Your vertices array is 2 dimensional but you accessing it like a 1 dimensional. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The array dimensionality seems correct to me, as glVertex2fv takes an array.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I switched it to double and it still does not draw anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current coordiantes and transformations, your object is just off the screen.

When setting all transformation matrices to identity, you are directly drawing in clip space. And if you do never use an input `w` value other than 1 (`glVertex2*` will always set `w` to 1), clip space equals normalized device space. In normalized device space, the viewing volume is defined as the cube [-1,1] along all dimensions.

However, by applying `glScale(2.0, 2.0, 0.0)`, you scale the object by 2, with the center beeing the origin. As a result, the visible part of the scene is everything in the range [-0.5,0.5] in object space coordinates, and your object is completely outside of that range.

If you want to scale on a single object, you should first translate it to the center, and apply the scale afterwards.
The following sequence of transformations should make your object visible:

```
glScalef(2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(0.9285f, -0.9285f, 0.0f);
```

Also note that all of that is *deprecated* in modern GL. You are relying on the fixed function pipeline with the integrated matrix stack, immediate mode (Begin/End) rendering, `GL_POLYGON` primitive type, which is all *removed* from modern core profiles of OpenGL. If you are starting with GL nowadyays, I strongly recommend learning the new way.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is showing up now. In terms of the way I am doing it, I am taking a class and I believe he wants us to use the methods I am.

Comment: @user3373291: Well, it's kind of funny. When asking people why they use such horribly outdated GL constructs, there is like a 50% chance the answer beeing "I'm attending some computer graphics class" (the other 50% are usually referring to some as-outdated tutorial on the web). You should make your teacher/lecturer aware that this kind of stuff is really not how we do graphics any more, in the 21st century...